# Wordpress hooks like posts filters

Tags: php, wordpress

I created user custom field from ACF (latitude, longitude), [i found this class](https://gschoppe.com/wordpress/location-searches/) that fits my needs, my goal is to find users 20km around.
The problem: this class is created for posts, and I'd like to adapt it for the wp_users table, but i haven't found any equivalences for these filters used by the class :

```
add_filter( 'posts_fields' , array( $this, 'posts_fields'  ), 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_join'   , array( $this, 'posts_join'    ), 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_where'  , array( $this, 'posts_where'   ), 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', array( $this, 'posts_orderby' ), 10, 2 );
```

My query is like this :

```
$latitude = get_field("latitude", "user_" . $current_user_id);
$longitude = get_field("longitude", "user_" . $current_user_id);

$args = array(
'geo_query' => array(
        'lat_field' => '_latitude',
        'lng_field' => '_longitude',
        'latitude'  => floatval($latitude),
        'longitude' => floatval($longitude),
        'distance'  => 20,
        'units'     => 'km'
     ),
     'role'         => 'buyer',
     'orderby'      => 'login',
     'order'        => 'ASC',
);
$users = new WP_User_Query($args);
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you!